# URL mapping with Azure and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, azure

I have what is probably a relatively simple question, however I seem to be searching the wrong things as I have been unable to find anything specific to my needs, and I'm not experienced enough with the subject matter to successfully implement what I have found in my context.

I have a PHP website hosted on Microsoft Azure, and currently have several files such as Index.php, About.php, SomeService.php etc, which can obviously be accessed through URLs such as

```
myazurehost.net/SomeService.php
```

However, I would like to be able to manipulate the URL mapping, for two reasons.
Firstly, and more importantly, I would like to be able to build directories such as

```
myazurehost.net/ServiceGroup/SomeService
```

Since this would be a lot neater and more maintainable than having individual files such as

```
myazurehost.net/SomeService.php
myazurehost.net/AnotherService.php
```

As this is undesirable for obvious reasons.

Secondly I would like to be able to alter the directory such that if a user visits the URL

```
myazurehost.net/SomeService
```

They see the page of SomeService.php, as currently visiting /SomeService would result in a 404 as SomeService is not the same as SomeService.php.

I believe I will need to use an equivalent of Apache's .htaccess system, however unless I'm mistaken this isn't available under Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Azure Web Apps use IIS to host your application. The best equivalent of Apache's `.htaccess` system is actually using `web.config` file to handle URL rewrite in IIS.

For example, you can just put the following `web.config` file into your web app's root folder to hide .php extension. For more info, please refer to https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-hide-php-extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is that meant to be good to go? I created a web.config file matching that and it meant that everything but index.php couldn't be found.

Comment: I have updated my reply for adding `<rules>` tag. Please try it again.